# Selecting specific columns from a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

everybody!!
I have a question.
Imagine a Data Frame with columns [a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j]. I want to create a 2nd DF having only columns a, c-g. How can I do this in a single coman without creating a list putting ao the columns? For example, I'm writing in that way:

```
columns = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
df2 = df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(columns)]
```

I would know if there's something more like:

```
df2 = df.loc[:,'a': 'g']
```

But excluing the 'b' column.

This second way I did 2 comands, one to select from a-g and the second, to drop b.

I would like to know if I can selct from a-g and drop b at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use slice notation `.loc` as you demonstrated along with a call to `.drop` to remove any specific unwanted columns:

### Create data

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[*range(10)]]*5, columns=[*'abcdefghij'])
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
3  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
4  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

### `.loc` and dropping

Fairly straightforward, use `.loc` to perform your slicing then `drop` anything you don't want from there.

```py
>>> df.loc[:, 'a':'g'].drop(columns='b')
   a  c  d  e  f  g
0  0  2  3  4  5  6
1  0  2  3  4  5  6
2  0  2  3  4  5  6
3  0  2  3  4  5  6
4  0  2  3  4  5  6
```

### Working With the Index

If you want to work as efficiently as possible with the index, you can use `Index.slice_indexer` along with `.drop` so that you don't create temporary subsets of your data (like we did above):

```py
>>> columns = df.columns[df.columns.slice_indexer('a', 'g')].drop('b')
>>> df[columns]
   a  c  d  e  f  g
0  0  2  3  4  5  6
1  0  2  3  4  5  6
2  0  2  3  4  5  6
3  0  2  3  4  5  6
4  0  2  3  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thank you!! The lock and dropping method was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
df2 = df[[a, c, d, e, f, g]].copy()
```

or

```
df2 = df.copy()
del df2[b]
```

Comment: I was wondering if a have a solution like your 1st one, but with the necessity to specify column by column.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you could solve this if you did not want to manually have to write in the columns into a list

```
#Firstly, if you wanted to simply pull back only columns that are sequential you could use an np.arange() to get the column indexes pulled back
df.iloc[:,np.arange(2, 5).tolist()]

#Secondly, if you wanted to pull back some columns sequential, but remove one in the middle you could use a pop on a list of ints to represent your column index
column_list = np.arange(2, 5).tolist()
#This pop will remove the 1 index of the list you created in the np.arange() above
column_list.pop(1)
df.iloc[:,column_list]
```

Comment: Thank your fow your answer. I was thinking in some to do all this as one liner

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which offers an abstraction.

I'll be reusing @CameronRiddell's sample data:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd 
import janitor

df = pd.DataFrame([[*range(10)]]*5, columns=[*'abcdefghij'])

# pass in the arguments:
df.select_columns('a', slice('c','g'))

   a  c  d  e  f  g
0  0  2  3  4  5  6
1  0  2  3  4  5  6
2  0  2  3  4  5  6
3  0  2  3  4  5  6
4  0  2  3  4  5  6
```

You can pull this off without another library using Pandas `filter`:

```py
df.filter(regex = '[ac-g]')
   a  c  d  e  f  g
0  0  2  3  4  5  6
1  0  2  3  4  5  6
2  0  2  3  4  5  6
3  0  2  3  4  5  6
4  0  2  3  4  5  6
```